# JavaScript function about local storage

Tags: javascript

I have an UI with 4 navigation: `Home`, `Page 1`, `Page 2`, `Page 3`

```HTML
<ul class="nav nav-pills mt-3 mb-5 ml-5">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" onclick="visitLink('Page1')" href="page_1.html">Page 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" onclick="visitLink('Page2')" href="page_2.html">Page 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" onclick="visitLink('Page3')" href="page_3.html">Page 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<button type="button" onclick="viewResults()" 
        class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block mb-5">
  View page visits results
</button>
```

And a function increasing the times we click 3 navs Page 1, Page 2, Page 3 seperated (I use path is a key, and the times is value):

```
function visitLink(path) {
    
    if (localStorage.getItem(path) === null) {
        // Store
        localStorage.setItem(path, "0");
    }
    localStorage.setItem(path, parseInt(localStorage.getItem(path)) + 1);
    return localStorage.getItem(path);
}
```

The function to display the result of each clicks in each page (it's not completed, I used this to debug):

```
function viewResults() {
  alert("You visited Page time(s) " + visitLink('Page1'))
}
```

But when I saw the result, it increased the result by 2, not 1 if I click Home button (count as 1 time of clicking) to return to see the result. How can I fix that?

Comment: You could use `localStorage.getItem` instead of `visitLink` in your `viewResults` function

Comment: @2pichar because we cannot change the html file, so that I must implement 2 functions: visitLink and viewResults

Comment: the extra increase is because you are calling `visitLink('Page1')` in your display function

Comment: Tks, it's have been solved. I'm calling the visitLink function again in viewResults so that it also increases by 1

Answer (score 2):

The result is two because you are calling `visitLink` to retrieve the count, which also increments the count.

Given that [you must implement the task with two functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71565230/javascript-function-about-local-storage/71565276#comment126484363_71565230), I would suggest adding another parameter to the `visitLink` function which indicates whether the count should be incremented:

```js
function visitLink(path, readonly) {
  if (localStorage.getItem(path) === null) {
    localStorage.setItem(path, "0");
  }
  if(!readonly){
    localStorage.setItem(path, parseInt(localStorage.getItem(path)) + 1);
  }
  return localStorage.getItem(path);
}

function viewResults() {
  alert("You visited Page time(s) " + visitLink('Page1', true))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function that increases the counter here `alert("You visited Page time(s) " + visitLink('Page1'))`, when calling `visitLink('Page1')`you fetch the result but also increase it

This should fix it, although I would recommend a `getResult` function

```
alert("You visited Page time(s) " + localStorage.getItem('Page1'))
```